# Angular2 Pipe filter with object

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to be able to filter a list object when I type in the input. But it keep give me an error.
I think it have to do with pipe not be able to read the value correctly.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(values: any[], filter: string): any[] {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;

    return values.filter(v => v.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input [(ngModel)]="filterString" />
      <div *ngFor="let d of (data | filter: filterString)">
        {{ d.id }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data = [{id: 1, leagueName: 'Recreation League' },
  {id: 2, leagueName: 'Recreation League' },
  {id: 3, leagueName: 'Recreation League' }
  ]; 

  filterString = '';

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, FilterPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The exact error message you get would be tremendously helpful ;-)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for helping me out. I just post it the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is really not an appropriate use of pipes in Angular. I know AngularJS (i.e. Angular 1) had a 'filter filter' but that was before, when there was a digest cycle.

A better approach would be to move that filtering into a method on your component.

Answer (score 1):

After ton of research and digging the code. Here is how I get it to work. The problem is that filter needs to compare the object's value not object. So, basically change

```
return values.filter(v => v.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
```

to

```
return values.filter(v => v.email.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
```

Here is the final result.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(values: any[], filter: string): any[] {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;
    // Filter items array, items which match will return true
    return values.filter(v => v.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```